# Heroku local doesn't read my .env file

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I tried the heroku node sample at:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

And used Postgres as the db.

All worked.

Now I wanted to run it local, so I used the sample from:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

To get the DATABASE_URL to my .env file - but I couldn't get it to work even though when I ran Heroku local it displayed:

```
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
```

The database still did not connect and when I added:

```
 console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
```

It wrote undefined to the console.

Comment: Created a short blog post on how to solve this issue after encountering it as well: https://www.jtrocinski.com/posts/Heroku-Running_a_Python_App_Locally.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out the for some reason my .env file was not in the correct unicode encoding.

I suspect that the command:

```
heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -s  >.env
```

Creates an invalid .env file on my windows machine. It creates a file using UTF-16 LE encoding.

Once I changed it to UTF-8 it all worked.

You can do that in VSCODE by clicking on the encoding in the status bar.
[image]

Comment: I was pretty excited when I saw your question and answer as I have the same issue with a React application.  Sadly, my issue appears different as the file is UTF-8.  My .env file works properly for the Heroku Example project, but not my own.  @noam,  any ideas?

Comment: @MobileVet
Rename the .env file - and create your own .env file and copy the text from the one created by heroku to the one you've created.

Also - in reality I don't use Heroku to serve locally, and I use an npm package to read the .env file called "dotenv"

Comment: Excellent find.

Comment: This solved my problem as well.  I find it best to use Git Bash as the default terminal in VS Code to avoid these sort of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to MobileVet's comment:

If it is a create-react-app, the env var MUST start w/ REACT_APP_.
That solved it for me...
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

And don't forget to restart.